# React.Component 'this' changed in ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fiber

How can be possible that 'this' in React.Component life cycle have changed to different object?
In `render()` and in `componentDidMount()` `this` points to different objects?

1. I use React 16.0.0
2. All life-cycle methods called only once
3. I transpile Typescript with Webpack
4. I couldn't repeat it in a browser, in browser `one === two // true`
5. I have very big app, so I thought it can be ReactFiber some kind of optimization?

Like here: [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/qenixobosa/edit?html,js,console,output)

[image: This is changed]
[image]

Comment: Can you copy your code where you make your test ? Can you output the value of one and two ?

Comment: could it be a copy and not a reference thus different object values (assigned at different times)?

Comment: @ChrisR added a screen, Lukasz about what variabe you talk about? `one` and `two` or `this`

Comment: @MiheyMik in your JSBin it returns `true` (I had to add `<div id ="app" />` to the HTML so the component renders).

Comment: @MiheyMik one and two as this is the reference to the object. I think using Object.assign copies properties as new object thus you have a snapshot that will differ over time as React will change some props.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the `two` has more properties. It's because at first output in constructor it's a pure Javascript Class. And then, React comes along and alter the Class before, during and after the render.

Comment: Well, get it, but this doesn't answer my question, why this changes to different object

Comment: It **is** the same object, it just doesn't have the same properties after being altered by React. So the `===` strict equality expression returns false.

Comment: this isn't how js `===` operator works. the object is same when variable pointers to the same object from left and right sides of `===`

Answer (score 0):

Take this example:

```
var a = {one:"1"};

var b = a;

a==b  // true
a===b // true
var c = Object.assign({}, a);

c     //{one: "1"}
a===c // false
a==c  // false
```

The call to `Object.assign` created a copy of the object thus inequality.

Comment: Lukasz this doesn't answer my question. `Object.assign` - assigns new properties to the first argument. In my case is 'window' object. So this lets me aterwards in the console see `one` and `two` values